# Python - Get "subarrays" of 3d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to get multiple subarrays of an 3D array. I can split the array in 2D case with a function found in a post of Stack :

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    h, w = arr.shape
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

and so i would like to extend it to 3D array case, form block as 2D arrray but in each slice in first dimension. I try with a "for loop" but doesnt work...

As example :

```
import numpy as np

#2D case (which works)

test=np.array([[ 2.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 3.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.]])

def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols): 

    h, w = arr.shape
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))


sub = blockshaped(test, 2,2)
```

And I get 4 "subarrays":

```
array([[[ 2.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 3.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.],
        [ 1.,  1.]]])
```

But for a 3D-array as input:

```
test2=np.array([[[ 2.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 3.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.]],

       [[ 5.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 2.,  1.,  1., 1.],
        [ 1.,  1.,  1., 1.]]])
```

So here I would like the same decomposition but in the 2 "slices"...

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols): 

    h, w, t = arr.shape 
    return (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1,2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
```

I try with a "for loop" but doesnt work:

```
for i in range(test2.shape[0]):                     
    sub = blockshaped(test[i,:,:], 2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You for loop solution would work doing something like:

```
sub = np.array([blockshaped(a, 2, 2) for a in test2])
```

But you can slightly modify `blockshaped()`, reshaping the data before and after the slicing:

```
def blockshaped(arr, nrows, ncols):
    need_reshape = False
    if arr.ndim > 2:
        need_reshape = True
    if need_reshape:
        orig_shape = arr.shape
        arr = arr.reshape(-1, arr.shape[-1])
    h, w = arr.shape
    out = (arr.reshape(h//nrows, nrows, -1, ncols)
               .swapaxes(1, 2)
               .reshape(-1, nrows, ncols))
    if need_reshape:
        new_shape = list(out.shape)
        new_shape[0] //= orig_shape[0]
        out = out.reshape([-1,] + new_shape)
    return out
```

Comment: I try with the modified function, the form seems to be good, but the shape is little strange : (2, 4, 2, 2). I expected (2,2,2) no? Thanks for help ;)

Comment: @user3601754 it should return exactly as `np.array([blockshaped(a, 2, 2) for a in test2])`, isn't that right?

Comment: It was the same in 2D case, the dimension was : (4, 2, 2)! It must work